# If Oracle uses PL/SQL for stored procedures, and SQLServer uses TSQL, what does MySQL use?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, plsql

Firstly, I believe similar questions have been asked in the past, but I believe these (and their answers) were posted prior to MySQL's implementation of Stored Procedures (or routines.)

I am aware that SQL Server uses TSQL, and Oracle uses PL/SQL. So, I'm just wondering what MySQL's is called, and if possible some advantages/disadvantages of that compared to the other two.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks, I have already done research and seen this page. It doesn't say any kind of name though. I'm wondering if it even has one.

Comment: @SamM that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Believe it or not I've been searching for ages and never found it haha.